# Formatting custom class output in PyYAML

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I'm working on a simple example here, but the docs still leave me a bit confused. 
 Here is the Example code:

```
class A(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!A'

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = datetime.time()
    a = A(t)
    print yaml.dump(a)
    print yaml.load(yaml.dump(a)).val == t
```

The output is

> !A val: !!python/object/apply:datetime.time ["\0\0\0\0\0\0"]
>
> True

So, it appears to be faithfully d-/serializing, but the default time object format leaves something to be desired. How can I make it prettier while preserving my mighty dump/load powers?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Redefine time format for all times in a document

You can define your own serialization format for any `datetime.time` instances in your documents using [PyYAML 'representers' and 'constructors'](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers).

```
import datetime

import yaml

time_format = '%H:%M:%S'


def time_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'!time', data.strftime(time_format))


def time_constructor(loader, node):
    value = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, time_format).time()


yaml.add_representer(datetime.time, time_representer)
yaml.add_constructor(u'!time', time_constructor)


class A(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!A'

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = datetime.time()
    a = A(t)
    print yaml.dump(a, default_flow_style=False)
    print yaml.load(yaml.dump(a)).val == t
```

Will output:

```
!A
val: !time '00:00:00'

True
```

### Redefine time format only for a particular class

You can also define how to a particular class serializes and deserializes. This way you can just change how time is represented for `A` only. [Docs for YAMLObject](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#YAMLObject)

```
import datetime

import yaml

time_format = '%H:%M:%S'

class A(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!A'

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, dumper, data):
        dict_representation = {
            'val':data.val.strftime(time_format)
        }
        node = dumper.represent_mapping(u'!A', dict_representation)
        return node

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, loader, node):
        dict_representation = loader.construct_mapping(node)
        val = datetime.datetime.strptime(
            dict_representation['val'], time_format).time()
        return A(val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = datetime.time()
    a = A(t)
    print yaml.dump([t,a], default_flow_style=False)

    loaded = yaml.load(yaml.dump([t,a]))
    print loaded[0] == t
    print loaded[1].val == t
```

Will output:

```
- !!python/object/apply:datetime.time
  - "\0\0\0\0\0\0"
- !A
  val: 00:00:00

True
True
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So when you change the way yaml represents datetime.time objects, you change it globally? That's fine for my purposes, and you definitely answered my question, but I figured there would be a class-specific way of doing this, so that I wouldn't change how other classes serialized datetime.time instances?